# Date format in Java

Tags: java, datetime, date

Few questions:

1. How can I print now (The current Date/Time) in the format below.
2. How can I convert a string date, into a date object if I know the format, same format as below.

Example:
    2011-05-04 19:12:46 -0500

Format:
    YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS [+|-]hh[mm]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
Date yourDate = new Date(...);
SimpleDateFormat myDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
System.out.print(myDateFormat.format(yourDate);
```

The link to SimpleDateFormat Javadoc is [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Also, `myDateFormat.parse(yourDateString)` to go back the other way.

Comment: How about taking in a date in string format, and converting it into a Date object?

Comment: @Jacob Nelson, see my above comment!

Answer (score 3):

Check out SimpleDateFormat: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

SimpleDateFormat.format() and SimpleDateFormat.parse()